# numpy.save() get MemoryError

Tags: numpy

When I used np. save() to save a fairly large file, a MemoryError occurred. How do I save files correctly?
I tried use pickle.dump(array, fp, protocol=-1, **pickle_kwargs)

```
 File "C:\Users\admin\.conda\envs\fastsam\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\data\dataset.py", line 94, in cache_labels
    np.save(str(path), x)  # save cache for next time
  File "C:\Users\admin\.conda\envs\fastsam\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 546, in save
    format.write_array(fid, arr, allow_pickle=allow_pickle,
  File "C:\Users\admin\.conda\envs\fastsam\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 719, in write_array
    pickle.dump(array, fp, protocol=3, **pickle_kwargs)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Looks like `x` is not a numeric numpy array.  `save` creates an array, possibly object dtype, and saves that.  Non-array elements have to be `pickled`, converted to a  string that can be saved to a file.  One or more of those elements produces a `pickle` string that is too large for memory.  There's nothing we can do remotely to solve this.  Obviously you can't share `x`, or its contents, on line.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you very much. I have already solved this problem by increasing the swap space to aviod memory error.